# Rails 4, record not-persisted in after create callback & Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, delayed-job

I've a really expensive method to run after creating an instance of a 'Klass', so I want to queue the job in DelayedJob.

```
class Klass
  has_many :klass_instances
  after_create :create_klassinstances

  def create_klassinstances
    .....
    delay.create_if_ok_to_create_klass_instances
    .....
  end

end
```

However this throws the error

```
#<ArgumentError: job cannot be created for non-persisted record:
```

Which I don't really understand. I am using an 'after_create' call back so surely an ID must exist now for the Klass record? I've played around with pry and calling 'self' in the create_klassinstances method returns the non persisted object with the ID set as nil.

Answer (score 0):

The `after_create` callback will not have access to the persisted object, and therefore the object will not have an id. You will have to use the `after_save` callback to access the object's id. To prevent the creation of a delayed job during future saves you can try something like this:

```
class Klass
  has_many :klass_instances
  after_save :create_klass_instances

  def create_klass_instances
    delay.now_create_klass_instances if klass_instances.empty?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[This Chap](http://logicalfriday.com/2012/08/21/rails-callbacks-workers-and-the-race-you-never-expected-to-lose/) gave me the answer I was looking for.

In summary, use `after_commit`

The problem is that Delayed Job has snatched the job off the queue and tried to process it before your database transaction has completed. So when it calls to the database to find your new record, it won’t actually be there, even though you said “after save”.